# twitter user age

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp

I need to know how to get age and gender of Twitter user?

I am using TweetSharp v2, but if you have any way to get this info will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I checked my Twitter settings and I don't see an option for gender or date of birth.

Comment: I see that but in some aplications i see they give this analitics gender percent and age percent.

Comment: Can you share the application name?

Comment: sproutsocial.com lists several other services they track -- they might allow you to get gender/age data, but it's not available on Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

According to Twitter Employee @episod Taylor Singletary,

> Demographic data such as this is not available from the API -- and not
>   always appropriate as Twitter accounts can represent many things not
>   limited to persons alive or dead.

Read his answer [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5030)